# Cisco ASR 1001 X SSH Connection

Tags: ssh

I am trying to set up SSH on Cisco ASR 1001X device. I am at a point where I am getting the login prompt for SSH, the authentication is successful, but immediately after that the connection closes. 
Here is my SSH configuration

```
aaa authentication login ssh local
!
!
!
!
!
aaa session-id common
!
transport-map type persistent ssh sshhandler
time-out 30
authentication-retries 4
rsa keypair-name sshkeys
transport interface GigabitEthernet0
connection wait allow interruptible
```

I am getting the below error when i checked the logs -

```
Jun  7 20:37:24.837: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console
*Jun  7 20:37:32.552: %SSH-5-SSH2_SESSION: SSH2 Session request from 12.12.12.3 (tty = 0) using crypto cipher 'aes256-ctr', hmac 'hmac-sha1' Succeeded
*Jun  7 20:37:36.114: %SSH-5-SSH2_USERAUTH: User 'acumensec' authentication for SSH2 Session from 12.12.12.3 (tty = 0) using crypto cipher 'aes256-ctr', hmac 'hmac-sha1' Succeeded
*Jun  7 20:37:36.118: %SSH-5-SSH2_CLOSE: SSH2 Session from 12.12.12.3 (tty = 0) for user 'acumensec' using crypto cipher 'aes256-ctr', hmac 'hmac-sha1' closed
```

Can anyone please check this ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Confirm that the SSH versions at host and Cisco ASR match ( either version 1, or 2 at both ends)
2. Try ssh from [putty](http://www.putty.org/)
3. Try again after closing all other access connections like telnet and console.
4. Make sure the modulus value is a power of 2. Try a value around 2K or less

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue, but your configuration does not show the VTY ports.  Verify that your VTY ports do not have "no exec" configured, especially VTY 0.  If they do, they will not allow an interactive logon.